# How to protect my program?

Tags: copyright, copy-protection

I want to release a program, my first program, but I don't know how to protect it. By protecting it I mean protect it against piracy and getting copied by others. Is there anything I can do to protect it? Can I protect the program or the code?

Comment: What language did you use? There are various obfuscators and packers to block reverse engineering and debugging, if that's what you want.

Comment: If the software runs on a server under you control, you can protect it. If the software runs on the end user machine, it can be copied... we would be in the realm of mitigation (e.g. obfuscation). If the target market are enterprises, I would like to encourage legal protection instead.

Comment: Can you protect your program? Yes, in various ways. Effectively enough that the effort is worth the averted damage? Very probably not.

Comment: **Don't release it.** Consider a [SaaS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_as_a_service) approach. But the most probable is that nobody will use your program. Read absolutely [this paper](https://www.nber.org/papers/w7600) written by a Nobel prize in economics.

Comment: In every country, especially the USA, copyright laws are fierce and draconian, and it costs all of $35 to formally "register" your work (or, a "collection" of works) online.  https://copyright.gov.  Beyond that, don't worry about the inevitable thieves – because they are not your *customers.*  If your product is good, people will pay for it.  For more than the last 25 years I have sold (and continue to sell) a product that costs between $150 and $650 per copy.  I have sold thousands.  The license-code scheme is perfunctory and minimal:  it is "to keep the honest people out."

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how much effort you wont to put in protection. Most popular software is pirated, so there is no foolproof method of protection. If somebody insists to use your software without paying, there isn't much you can do.

If your software is not widely distributed, your best course is to protect it just so that it's not trivial to copy it, like requiring a key that you send separately after purchase. Be sure to display that the software is not free and to offer an easy purchase. Include the name of the user who purchased the software on the title screen so that it's obvious that the software is legal or copied.

Comment: It's fine and customary to display the registered owner's name and the license expiration date if any.  But, I must stress from experience:  "don't overly inconvenience your *customers* and don't project the idea that you don't trust them."  Generally follow the practices that you see your competitors using.  Some customers like governments are *legally required* to not spend public money on something that does not have some kind of licensing control mechanism.  But, once the product is installed it should be "out of sight, out of mind."  If your stuff's good, they *will* quite-willingly pay!